Одновременная работа Polling и Webhook в Aiogram 3
Стоит следующая задача: бот отрабатывает нажатие кнопки старт, записывает данные и переводит пользователя в чат с оператором. Этот чат работает в интеграции с OkoCRM. Туда вводиться token бота и чат работает внутри crm.
Но при таком раскладе, весь остальной фнукционал бота ложиться и я вижу замечательную ошибку
Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active
DeleteWebHook наоборот же, оставляет все, кроме работы с чатом.
Как можно решить такую задачу? Спасибо.
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
import asyncio

from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from config import TOKEN_API

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN_API)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher()


async def start():
    from handlers import router
    from handlers import get_start
    dp.include_router(router)
    dp.message.register(get_start, Command(commands='start'))
    try:
        print('Бот запущен')
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())

